# Use ELMAH with Azure Mobile Servies

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services, elmah, httpmodule

For logging unhandled exceptions, I used ELMAH with several ASP.NET MVC and Web API projects so far.
Now I'm trying to use it for my Azure Mobile Services backend but I can't get it to log any errors. I configured it like a regular Web Api project.
Do I have to plug in ELMAH differently for AMS (OWIN pipeline) or is it not possible to plug a HttpModule to AMS anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Mobile Services .NET runtime takes over the default trace writing pipeline, which makes things a bit more difficult. You may try looking at this blog post on logging in the .NET runtime:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/24/logging-with-the-net-backend-for-azure-mobile-services.aspx